# storing custom object with different primitive types in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, custom-object

I want to create a custom object with three ints and a String and store that object in an arrayList, but I seem to be having issues with it and haven't been able to find documentation for exactly my issue online. I'm getting errors on the fac.add. here is the code

**made some changes to the code

```
package facility;
import dal.DataAccess;

public class FacilityInfo implements Facility {

private int buildingNo, roomNo, capacity;; 
private String type; //classroom, conference room, office, etc.

FacilityInfo(){}//default constructor

FacilityInfo(int b, int r, int c, String t){
    this.buildingNo = b; 
    this.roomNo = r; 
    this.capacity = c; 
    this.type = t; 
} 
package dal;
import java.util.*;

import facility.FacilityInfo;

public class DataAccess {
    List<FacilityInfo> fac = new ArrayList<FacilityInfo>();
    fac.add(new FacilityInfo (1,2,10,conference));//changed code here
}
```

Comment: There's an extra semicolon on the line where you're declaring the 3 `int` fields.

Comment: Sidenote : Also you don't need to use `this.` to refer to the global variable unless the variable name is the same as the constructor parameters.

Comment: @MasterYushi The default constructor is only done automatically when there are no defined constructors.

Comment: @4castle Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of two main reasons.

First, `1,2,10,conference` isn't a `FacilityInfo` object.  You can't add the arguments of a `FacilityInfo` to the `List`, you have to add an actual object.

Second, you can't have statements outside of a code block, and currently you are calling `fac.add(...);` directly in the class body.

Try something like:

```
public class DataAccess {
    List<FacilityInfo> fac = new ArrayList<FacilityInfo>();

    public void initializeFac() {
        fac.add(new FacilityInfo(1,2,10,"conference"));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also the issue of how `fac.add` is being called in the class body, and not in a method.

Comment: Yes, method calls need to be inside a method

Comment: thanks i did this and created a method for it and put it there instead of the class body and this worked

Comment: @4castle Oops! Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer to include both errors.